# GirdView with a large first item

Tags: android, listview, gridview

i wonder if there is a way to implement a GridView which first item is for example twize as large as the rest of the items.
I think this screenshot of an iPad App describes best what i want to achieve:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on for what android versions you want to develop for:

Android versions prior 3.0 (Honeycomb) doesnt support column or row spans in GridViews,
so you have to implement your own ViewGroup (You can extend the very basic FrameLayout).
Started with Android 3.0 you can use the GridLayout class to do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, unfortunately i need 2.3 too, so FrameLayout it is :-(